Is it possible to have more than one context (database) but only one set of migrations?
For my systems I generally have three databases: Development, Testing, and Production.
The way I do this is by having one abstract base class that inherits from DbContext and accepts a connection string in its constructor. I then have three concrete classes that inherit from that base class, each passing a different connection string (and with a default constructor so that migrations can call it).
public abstract class MyBaseContext(
   string connectionString
) : DbContext {
   ...
}

public sealed class MyProductionContext()
: MyBaseContext(productionConnectionString);

public sealed class MyDevelopmentContext()
: MyBaseContext(developmentConnectionString);

public sealed class MyTestingContext()
: MyBaseContext(testingConnectionString);

I can then use something like this:
dotnet ef migrations add AddSomeNewFields --context MyDevelopmentContext
dotnet ef database update --context MyDevelopmentContext

to add a new migration with some new changes, and to apply it to the particular database.
The issue with this is that I end up with three sets of migrations for three databases.
Is there some way that I can generate only one set of migrations and apply that one set of migrations to multiple database instances?

Does it work if you have an abstract class as a common base class for all three DbContext? Just a suggestion I am not sure if it works.

@LukeVo thanks, but that is my setup already

Is MyDevelopmentContext your base class? I was wondering if it's possible to use the base class as the migrations' DbContext and your actual DbContext may be able to be updated from it?

@LukeVo well, if it wasn't abstract, then I could maybe use the base. but then it would not target any particular database. I would need to give it a connection string somehow. I guess, yeah, I need to use the same context but target a different DB. Is there a way to do that?

I don't see why you need 3 contexts, just pass connection string with dotnet script?

Yeah I thought you needed some specific DI for each env. In this case, like the other comment, why don't you simply configure the Connection String with a single DbContext class instead? Heck you could even use appsettings.Development.json etc if you don't want to use a deploy script.

@YehorAndrosov ok, how do I do that? I don't see a --connectionstring option with dotnet ef migrations add. And could I pull the value from somewhere or would I have to do it "manually" each time (though probably in a .bat file)?

Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-8.0

@LukeVo it seems like that's about configuration from c# code which I already can do; but how do I get configuration values when at the command-line and pass it to dotnet ef? (It sounds like maybe I'm supposed to use environment variables?)

I believe you can use a factory for it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory. As for updating, I usually put that logic in the Startup code at runtime but you can also do that at deployment time with Publish Profile as well.

@LukeVo that seems promising, thanks

What I did (as hinted by comments) is implement from IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<TContext>.
This allows arbitrary command-line arguments to be fed to the construction of your context, without having to have different types of context. Where you get your configuration values is then still up to you, but this provides a mechanism to alter your context from the command-line any way you want.
I reduced my context to something like this:
public sealed class MyContext(
   string connectionString
) : DbContext {
   protected override void OnConfiguring(
      DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder
   ) =>
      optionsBuilder
      .Use...(connectionString);

   ...
}

And then implemented a context factory something like this:
public sealed class MyContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyContext> {
   public MyContext CreateDbContext(
      string[] args
   ) {
      if (args.Length != 1)
         throw new InvalidOperationException(...);

      var arg = args[0].ToLower();

      var cs = arg switch {
         "production" => productionConnectionString,
         "development" => developmentConnectionString,
         "testing" => testingConnectionString,
         _ => throw new InvalidOperationException(...)
      };

      return new MyContext(cs);
   }

   // these are for use in code
   public MyContext CreateProduction() => CreateDbContext("production");
   public MyContext CreateDevelopment() => CreateDbContext("development");
   public MyContext CreateTesting() => CreateDbContext("testing");
}

Then you can do the following from the command-line (the -- syntax causes the remainder of the command-line arguments to be passed as-is to your factory method):
dotnet ef migrations add SomeNewMigration -- development
dotnet ef database update -- development
dotnet ef database update -- production
dotnet ef database update -- testing

and that will use a single migration for all three database connections.

An example that uses appsettings.json might look like this:
public sealed class MyContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyContext> {
   public MyContext CreateDbContext(
      string[] args
   ) {
      if (args.Length != 1)
         throw new InvalidOperationException(...);

      var name = args[0];

      // you can use arguments to pull from a different settings file
      // or you can put full cnxn strings in the file under a
      //   "ConnectionStrings" grouping and use .GetConnectionString() 
      //   to find them
      // or you can put specific values like paths and build the rest 
      //   of the cs here
      //   index like: ["Key:Value"]
      // lots of options
      var cs =
         new ConfigurationBuilder()
         .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
         .Build()
         .GetConnectionString(name); // the arg you pass finds the cs by name
      if (cs == null)
         throw new InvalidOperationException(...);

      return new MyContext(cs);
   }

   // these are for use in code when you need a particular connection
   // ie: testing for testing
   public MyContext CreateProduction() => CreateDbContext("production");
   public MyContext CreateDevelopment() => CreateDbContext("development");
   public MyContext CreateTesting() => CreateDbContext("testing");
}

appsettings.json example:
{
   "ConnectionStrings": {
      "Production": "...",
      "Development": "...",
      "Testing": "..."
   }
}


While this looks good I think the standard way should be using DbContextOptions<MyContext> constructor (like in the DbContext base class) instead of just connection string like this one. Glad it works out for you though

You don't need to pass an environment to invoke dotnet ef migrations add - it uses local snapshot schema and current db context to compare.
dotnet ef database update, on the other hand, compares migrations in the project to the ones stored in the migration history table. If you have your connection string stored in appsettings.{Environment}.json file, you can use
dotnet ef database update -- --environment Production

It will read connection string from appsettings.Production.json
If you don't store credentials in configuration files, you can use --connection option
dotnet ef database update 20180904195021_InitialCreate --connection your_connection_string

Source

this doesn't seem to quite work as you say. I still need to specify an environment when adding, and I still need to implement IDesignTimeDbContext<T> in order to use the environment value to choose a connection string to pass to my context. unless my context has to be setup a certain way? note that this has nothing to do with ASP.NET. but the DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT variable is empty if I don't specify an environment value when adding.

well as far as I can tell this doesn't work at all. I think it needs much more setup that you haven't mentioned here.

will get back to computer  and prepare a demo

Thanks, I do have it working quite well with IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<T>. For this other stuff to work must require some other class to parse your arguments for you. But you may as well just handle them yourself in the CreateDbContext method and then you can handle it any way you want. Thanks for the responses though.

yep, i missed the part where it was going about .net core :-) creating an empty asp.net core object just for migrations is also an option
